# Google Play Services "Connecting" pop up does not appear

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have have implemented the Google Play Services and BaseGameUtils to my app. Everythings works fine, but when sign-in button is clicked there is no pop-up with displaying the sign in progess, after a few seconds sign-in progress ends succesfully and "Welcome -username-" pop up appears.

I didn't change anything but the sign-in progress doesn't appear. In developer.google.com it says "On Android devices, the Google Play Games 'Connecting' pop-up is displayed by default whenever the sign-in flow is invoked.". How can I solve this issue, any ideas?

Comment: Not sure of your issue, but the pop-up is only displayed on first sign-in, or after you've **signed-out** and sign-in again. Note that sign-out never happens during the normal flow - you have to manually call the `mHelper.signOut()` method to sign out (by default it only disconnects, which is different).

Comment: Yes @free3dom that is my issue thank you, I called signOut in onDestroy method and it is now showing the pop-up ;)

Comment: No problem, I'll add it as an answer to help future users with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sign-in pop-up is only displayed on first sign-in, or after you've signed-out and then sign-in again.

Note that sign-out never happens during the normal `GameHelper` flow, you have to manually call the `mHelper.signOut()` method to sign out - by default `GameHelper` only disconnects, which is different from signing-out.